# How to use a Point or Geometry type in Datamapper (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, geolocation, point, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm using codeigniter and datamapper to build an API service (on mysql), and part of it involves geolocation - however I can't seem to find a workaround to use the point datatype. If I try to insert GeomFromText, the system treats it as a string.

Can anyone help?

Cheers,
Mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CREATE TABLE Points ( 
    ID INT(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    location POINT NOT NULL, 
    SPATIAL INDEX(location) 
) ENGINE= MYISAM
```

In CodeIgniter:

```
$this->db->set("location",'geomfromtext("POINT(30.2 40.3)")',false);
$this->db->insert("Points");
```

In CodeIgniter with Datamaper (see help for "Using Formulas in Updates" in the documentation)...

```
$point = new Point();
$point->update('location','geomfromtext("POINT(30.2 40.3)")',FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the CodeIgniter User's Guide:

```
$this->db->set();
```

set function enables you to set values for inserts or updates.

set() will accepts a third parameter ($escape), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE.

```
$this->db->set('geo', "ST_GeomFromText('{$data['geo']}')", FALSE);
$this->db->insert('tableName');

return $this->db->insert_id() ? $this->db->insert_id() : FALSE;
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what your code does? A code-only answer can be misinterpreted by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use FLOAT as your database datatype.

Comment: [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html).-MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001. If you can not use Point, is preferable to use decimal.

Comment: Well, i've done crate a proxy library which support for geolocation(using google map service) in Codeigniter : http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/186250/, and works fine with my float datatype on my database.

Comment: It is not the same country as mailing addresses, and failure precision in MySQL is a design feature. In the manual refer to these fields as "Floating-Point (Approximate-Value) Types"... [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)